# JTable.getSelectedRow() returns wrong value

Tags: java, swing

In a project that uses javax.swing, the code goes like following:

```
JTable m_Table;
...

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    TableCellEditor editor = m_Table.getCellEditor();
    if( editor != null )
    {
        editor.stopCellEditing();
    }

    int row = m_Table.getSelectedRow();
    if( row < 0 )
    {
        row = 0;
    }
    // bug: if the cursor is in an edit box,
    // the row number happens to be greater by 1
```

The problem is that it looks like `row` is 1-based instead of 0-based, but only if the cursor is in a cell edit box.

Why getSelectedRow() returns a wrong value?

Comment: Can you write a [mcve] ? I am interested by the cause, not simply the workaround proposed

Comment: @AxelH the cause is that stopCellEditing() moves the focus to the next cell (if there _is_ one).

Comment: No, it will fire an event that will trigger every `CellEditorListener` and call [`CellEditorListener.editingStopped`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CellEditorListener.html#editingStopped(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent)). The listener is to update the value in the `JTable` (the `CellEditorListener`) with the one from the editor. Your focus changing has nothing to do with the method called. If you can't provide a [mcve], if you can reproduce the problem, this is probably because this is not the problem...

Comment: hmmm, good point. Indeed it may be because of listeners. If this is true, the side effect of stopCellEditing() is calling the listeners, and it is the listeners that advance the focus.

Answer (score 0):

stopCellEditing() has an undocumented side effect: it moves the focus to the next -- not sure what (cell? editable cell?) -- but that next thing was in the next row.

EDIT According to the comments, stopCellEditing() does not change the focus, but it calls listeners that can do that. (Well, moving the focus to the next field is a common pattern in application software.)

The remedy is to first getSelectedRow() and only then stopCellEditing().

Comment: `stopCellEditing() has an undocumented side effect: it moves the focus to the next` - no it doesn't. stopCellEditing() removes the editor from the table. The cell that was edited will retain focus. So, the question is how is your ActionListner invoked and why is this changing the cell with focus? Typically this is done by clicking on a button. So based on the context of your question we can't really tell you what is happening because you didn't provide a proper [mcve].